# jQuery dialog plugins just like an ads

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Does anyone know a jQuery plugin just like an `ads` popup that can show information? I want it to show it the page and put a search form area on it so that the client can search on the dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a popup in jQuery
all you have to do is change the content in the div
you could execute the script on load or when a link or button is clicked to do this you have to change the  function

resources

https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
});
</script>

<body>
  <div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
  </div>
</body>
```